# Submit form give empty value

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i submit login form  its give me empty value of field using codeigniter

```
public function verify()
{
    $where  = array(
            'usrEmail'      => $this->input->post("email"),
            'usrPassword'   => $this->input->post("password")

            );
```

this code and link is

```
  http://www.prajjali.com/website_dev/
```

please help
Thanks

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action="" in form from http://prajjali.com/website_dev/index.php/login/verify to http://www.prajjali.com/website_dev/index.php/login/verify and now it should work fine.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.prajjali.com/website_dev/index.php/login/verify">
```

The reason is that you get redirected to a URL that includes www. and when you get redirected the POST-data is lost.

Regards
Tobias